# Should we put question marks at the end of the following sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

The three sentences are:

1. Wouldn't it be good if we invited them over?
2. Wouldn't it be nice to have those kitchen utensils?
3. Wouldn't it be nice if we could have those kitchen utensils?

P.S. Another question. Which one of 2 and 3 is more grammatically correct?

Comment: Both 2 and 3 are correct, but have different meanings. the first makes a general statement that (for all people), having those utensils would be nice. The second makes a specific statement that (for us), having those utensils would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three sentences are marked as questions by **subject-auxiliary inversion**:

```
 1a.  Itsubj  wouldn'taux  be good 〔if we invited them over〕.
 1b.  Wouldn'taux  itsubj  be good 〔if we invited them over〕?
```

Example 1a is a statement.
Example 1b is a question—the subject ***it*** and the auxiliary ***wouldn't*** have switched places.

Since it's a question, you use a question mark `?` instead of a period `.`

---

The same is true of your other sentences:

```
 2a.  Itsubj  wouldn'taux  be nice 〔to have those kitchen utensils〕.
 2b.  Wouldn'taux  itsubj  be nice 〔to have those kitchen utensils〕?

 3a.  Itsubj  wouldn'taux  be nice 〔if we could have those kitchen utensils〕.
 3b.  Wouldn'taux  itsubj  be nice 〔if we could have those kitchen utensils〕?
```

All three questions are grammatical.